# Removing Sprites from stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, parent-child, sprite

Hey guys, got a problem with my pages in flash. So i created 5 pages, each of which contains several movie clips (text, graphics, forms, etc). There is one specific page however that contains autogenerated content via. sprites. If i happen to land on this page, the sprites will appear, but when i transition to another page, they are still there except for the non-sprite stuff (disappear). Im ripping my hair out on this one, i managed to get a few of the sprites to remove but some are still appearing. Below shows the layout of the one thats not being removed;

```
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();

//loop places several "item" in this container sprite and a scroll bar
var item:myItem = new myItem();
var sb:customScrollBar = new customScrollBar();

container.addChild(item);
container.addChild(sb);
```

So we are now on this page where container and items are generated, i then click a button to move to say the home page and the container still stays there.

Here is what i tried:

```
removeChild(container); //nothing, this was called from another keyframe where the container was not generated from
stage.removeChild(container); //nothing
```

Here are the errors.
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.

Note*
I also have several buttons that were also generated NOT inside the container like below and they worked when i ran removeChild(button1) so i dont know why the container one is not working.

FLA (cs4)
http://www.4shared.com/file/2swJjnNm/mevame.html

Preview
http://bodog-bonuses.com/mevame/

Comment: If you're getting the 'Supplied DisplayObject must be a child..' error, it sounds like the container isn't a child of the stage. You can check that with this: if (stage.contains(container)) { trace("true"); } . See what happens when you run that.

Comment: Hmm didnt know you can do that. I tried this and it returned true. Ive been fiddling with it and i get it to work sometimes and then out of nowhere when i try to do it again it fails.

Comment: you know what here is a link to the thing just so you can see it. http://bodog-bonuses.com/mevame/ , if you cycle through just the links on the menu, you will notice they all work. If you go into the menu tab then click on a salad (box), the calculator thing shows up. Now this is the auto generated stuff, notice if you go to any other page it still stays there. If you however go to the home it gets removed but only once.

Comment: Sounds strange, and hard to debug without having the project in front of me. Try putting a breakpoint at the line with the removeChild call, and then run the debugger, and see what's inside that object each time you run it. Also, check through your code and make sure you're not addChilding those objects to anywhere else. Otherwise, if you'd like to send some code I'll take a look.

Comment: hmmm, ok i will try debugging it. I edited the post so at the bottom there is a link to the fla but its cs5. (lemme know if you want me to convert it to cs4 or something else)

Comment: Ah, just saw you added the FLA, but I don't have CS5. If you save it as CS4 I'll try to take a look tomorrow.

Comment: where do you adding container to your stage??

Answer (score 1):

You will not get an Argument error 2025 IF you follow

```
//initialization
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();

...... 
......
addChild(container);

//------- later
if(contains(container))
  removeChild(container);
```

No need to create a name this is guarentee that the sprite or DisplayObject is added to the DisplayList. You will not get an y ArgumentError 2025 then.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me before which I solved by doing the following. It depends on how your instances of container I created and therefore recognized by the parent.

```
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
container.name = "container";

//------- later
var child:DisplayObject = getChildByName("container");
removeChild(child);
```

If you need to remove all children you could also do this

```
while( this.numChildrem > 0 )
     this.removeChildAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by that fact that with a timeline animation, any given keyframe may contain an object however with each keyframed list of actions, you lose scope on the previous keyframe's contents. So if you call remove child before you cross a new timeline keyframe, you will likely be able to successfully call removeChild on the container.

Otherwise, you can utilize Patrick's suggestion, which will definitely find the object on the stage and remove it, though it is one of the more inefficient means of retrieving an object from the display list.